# How can I run my macro on a differently named workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to run on files I download daily - they contain information on a select number of stocks. The macro bolds some columns, performs a calculation in a new column, sorts by that calculation (Z-A), and creates a text-joined list of the top x number of stocks to be imported into a watchlist on TradingView.

The macro only runs on workbooks of the same name. I tried to get around this by creating the macro under a standard file name and then manually changing the downloads to this name in Finder so the macro can run once I open the file and activate it.

This has been the only way to circumvent

> run time error 9: 'subscript out of range' error message.

**For example:**

*russell-2000-index-12-23-2021.csv* is the download name (date will vary) while *russell-2000-index.csv* the file name currently in the VBA code of the macro

Each day I download these, the file name will reflect the date of the download. I tried using VBA to edit the code to use a wildcard after the 'russell-2000-index' portion of the file name.

Edit:

[image: Code in Question]

My main question is how do I run my macro on a file name of, say, *russell-2000-index-12-23-2021.csv* or any variation on the date?

Comment: Are you using code to open the workbooks? If you include the relevant parts of your code there is probably an adjustment to be made. Please include that in your question.

Comment: With the exception of applying bold format, you could do everything you mentioned using Power Query. You could just download each day's file into a folder. File name will not matter if you specify get from folder. Consistent file structure is required.

Comment: braX - I edited my original post with a snapshot of the code in question.

Comment: bugdrown - I will have to look into this. Is Power Query an add-in for Excel or a separate program?

Comment: Are you using code to open the workbooks you want to run this code on? Are you doing that manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting the code into the workbook before running it, you can use the built in Object identifiers to refer to the workbook without using its name. Eg. `ThisWorkbook` instead of `Workbooks("Name")`.

If you are opening the workbook alongside your macro workbook/add-on then you can search through the Workbooks collection to find a name that matches your pre-defined patterns like

```vb
  Dim WB as Workbook, csvWB As Workbook
  For Each WB in Application.Workbooks
    If ... Then Set csvWB = WB
  Next WB
```

The key then, is to find a way to match the name of the workbook to your pattern. You can try using the [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) Operator.

`If FileName Like "russell-2000-index-??-??-????.csv" Then ...`

Or

`If FileName Like "russell-2000-index*" Then ...`

You can also use the [InStr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) function  to test if the string contains a specific sub-string. `InStr` returns the position of the substring if found in the main string, or 0 if not found. So we can test `<> 0` (not equal to zero).

`If Instr(1, FileName, "russell-2000-index", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ...`

Once you have successfully found the workbook using one of these methods, you can continue the rest of the macro by using the variable `csvWB` and not need to use the file name anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### Identify File by Date

```vb
Option Explicit

Function GetTodaysRussell() As String
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const BaseName As String = "russell-2000-index"
    Const Delimiter As String = "-"
    Const DateFormat As String = "mm-dd-yyyy"
    Const FileExtension As String = ".csv"
    
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & BaseName _
        & Delimiter & Format(Date, DateFormat) & FileExtension
    
    If Len(Dir(FilePath)) > 0 Then GetTodaysRussell = FilePath

End Function

Sub GetTodaysRussellTEST()
    
    Dim swbPath As String: swbPath = GetTodaysRussell
    
    If Len(swbPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Today's file hasn't been downloaded yet.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath)
    ' Continue...
    ' e.g.:
    MsgBox "Opened file '" & swb.Name & "'.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```